# java parse text from html without including links

Tags: java, jsoup, jericho-html-parser

I was trying to libraries jericho and jsoup. But unfortunately, the parsed text includes the links. In fact, I am trying to tokenize the html text to find keywords and these two libraries are generating lots of noises which are really difficult to handle.

```
public static String getPlainTextJsoup(String pageSrc) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageSrc);
        return doc.body().text();
    }

public static String getPlainTextExtractJericho(String htmlSrc) {
        Source src = new Source(htmlSrc);
        return src.getTextExtractor().setIncludeAttributes(true).toString();
    }
 public static String getPlainText(String html) {
        Source htmlSource = new Source(html);
        Segment htmlSeg = new Segment(htmlSource, 0, html.length());
        Renderer htmlRend = new Renderer(htmlSeg);
       // System.out.println(htmlRend.toString());
        return htmlRend.toString();
    }
```

With this link:

http://jobview.monster.com/Sr-Java-Developer-Job-Baltimore-MD-126949729.aspx

I am getting noises like:
1061349
20baltimore
2c
2f

all are coming from the link / src etc tags.

How can I prevent these link elements from showing up in the parsed text?

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to get the text from the jobBodyContent div?

Comment: No sir, I am trying to open the whole html file into a string and then passing the string to the getPlainText methods.

Comment: I tried it using JSoup and the only noise I got was some script tags, but that's how the HTML is written.  So the only way you can avoid that is to specifically parse the page and select which sections you care about.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the `a`s text to `""`?

like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();

    System.out.println(document.text());

    // replace the "a"s text
    for (Element element: document.getElementsByTag("a"))
    {
        element.text("");
    }
    System.out.println("Without a's");
    System.out.println(document.text());
}
```

It will print:

```
Google Suche Bilder Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive Mehr » Webprotokoll | Einstellungen | Anmelden × Schneller im Internet unterwegs Installieren Sie Google Chrome Deutschland   Erweiterte SucheSprachoptionen Werben mit GoogleUnternehmensangebote+GoogleÜber GoogleGoogle.com © 2013 - Datenschutzerklärung & Nutzungsbedingungen
Without a's
Google Suche | | × Schneller im Internet unterwegs Deutschland   © 2013 -
```